# Populate select element

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to populate a `<select>` element using the results from my `categories` table. In order to do that I use the following code.

```
$catlist = Categories::where('type','=',$content_type)
           ->get(array('id','name'))->toArray();
```

The result structure is an array of rows.

```
array
  0 => 
   array
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'article' 
  1 => 
   array
     'id' => int 2
     'name' => string 'news'
```

A `foreach` statement surely would solve my problem but I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: Shouldn't be your model named in singular ?

Comment: yes, you are right @yannishristofakis

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the [`lists(string $column [, string $key ])`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.2.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1426-L1455) method for this, found under ["Retrieving A List Of Column Values"](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects) in the documentation...

```php
$catlist = Category::where('type', $content_type)->lists('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add static function on you category model

```
public static function genlist()
{
    $catlist = [];
    foreach (self::all() as $cat)
    {
        $catlist[$cat->id] = $cat->name;
    }
    return $catlist;
}
```

view

```
{{ Form::select('cat_id', Category::genlist()) }}
```

this works to me, and hope will work to you also

Comment: I'm not much of a fan of this approach (although it does work). Your models shouldn't have knowledge of what is needed for your presentation layer. That's what presenters are for, or you could use some sort of transformer to generate the format you need.

Better yet, write an HTML macro that handles it for you :)