# Laravel - Populating Select List with Derived Values

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have an Eloquent model (Presenters) that has three columns: `id`, `first_name` and `last_name`.  What I want to do is populate the select options so that the id is the value, and the `first_name . last_name` is what is displayed.

For instance, if I had these presenters:

```
id, first_name, last_name
1, Billy, Bob
2, Jose, Cuervo
3, Puff, the Magic Dragon
```

I want something similar to this output:

```
<select name="presenters">
    <option value="1">Billy Bob</option>
    <option value="2">Jose Cuervo</option>
    <option value="3">Puff the Magic Dragon</option>
</select>
```

I know that if I only care about the last name or first name in the select list, I can do this:

```
{{ Form::select("presenters", Presenter::lists("first_name", "id"), Input::old("presenters"), array( "class" => "form-control" )) }}
```

There are [many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669943/populate-select-element) already regarding populating select inputs for models in Laravel, although I haven't found one yet that shows how to populate a select input where a derived value is to be shown in each of the options rather than just a single column.

Can I use the `lists` method to populate the select element, or will I need to populate my own array of values / option texts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Presenter::select('id', DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) AS full_name'))->lists('full_name', 'id');
```

Comment: Thanks Andreyco, this looks promising.. I'll try this and see if it works.

Comment: Works like a charm here :)

Answer (score 1):

You've provided the answer, look at the [PaulDM reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669943/populate-select-element?lq=1#answer-20624453)

Just adapt it, hope it works for you:

```
// your eloquent model ...
public static function listPresenters() {
    $ret = [];
    foreach (self::all() as $presenter) {
        $ret[$presenter->id] = "{$presenter->first_name} {$presenter->last_name}";
    }
    return $ret;
}
// your eloquent model ...
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm hoping to avoid this and use the built-in lists method, but thanks for the feedback.