# Laravel Populate Select with Concatenated String

Tags: php, laravel

I am attempting to populate a `select` box with the first and last name of a customer. I can't quite figure out how to concatenate the two strings before they are sent to the select box.

I currently have

```
public function getView($id) {
        $customers = DB::table('customers')->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')->lists('first_name', 'last_name', 'id');

        return View::make('vehicles.view')->with('customers', $customers);
    }
```

And in the View

```
{{ Form::label('customer', 'Customer Name') }}
                            {{ Form::select('customers', $customers, NULL, array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
```

But this only displays the first name, as expected. I know I need to do a `foreach` loop before the array is passed to the view, but I am not sure how to do this and keep the structure so it can render with the full name as the text and id as the value of the `select`.

Comment: Very similar to a question I had awhile ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20960108/697370

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you. I like this solution much better than a `foreach` loop.